# Different triggers same job?

Tags: sql, triggers, ddl

I have two triggers and I would like to know if the result of the work performed is the same.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_test_upd ON test AFTER UPDATE
AS
  RAISERROR('Error', 16, 1);
  ROLLBACK;
GO 

CREATE TRIGGER trg_test_upd ON test INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
  RAISERROR('Error', 16, 1);      
GO
```

Second question, why would you use `ROLLBACK` if you have `INSTEAD OF`?

Comment: The real question should, of course, be why would you have granted anyone `UPDATE` permissions on this table in the first place, if you're just then going to use a trigger to prevent updates from working?

Comment: For example you want to put some conditions on update related to the value you are updating .

Comment: If it's a *conditional* error/rollback then the triggers are not the same because the `INSTEAD OF` trigger needs to perform the actual changes if the condition is false. But, if that's the sort of case you want to discuss, the triggers you've shown in your question aren't representative and so how are we meant to know that?

Comment: That is my mistake . But my goal was to know if you can get rid of ROLLBACK  in every case .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two triggers work in the same way, except that the first will probably take more time.

Suppose your `test` table has a table with a million records. And you attempt to update some column for every record. Then first the update operation will happen, and only once updates on all the records complete, the trigger will be activated. The trigger will then raise the error and discard all the changes through the update statement using the `ROLLBACK` command.

In the second case, the trigger will be activated as soon as the update on the table is encountered. This will save quite a bit of unnecessary data processing. To answer your second question, the update operation does not execute in the second case when `INSTEAD OF` is used. Hence, there is no need of a `ROLLBACK` command.

Comment: Ok understood. But why in some case you would use rollback ?

Comment: In the first case, update takes place, so rollback is necessary to ensure the updates do not get committed later. In the second case, no update happened, so rollback is not needed. (You could add a rollback statement there too, but it would be redundant.)

Comment: Fine thank you . Do you have example where a rollback is necessary ?

Comment: Your first scenario is the best case I can present to you right now. Let's say you update a particular column in `test` for some of the records. Assume that the trigger has no rollback statement. And immediately after updating `test`, you need to update another table `test2`, where you update some records and there is no trigger on the update of that table. After your update on `test2`, you commit your changes. Then the changes to table `test` will also get committed along with the changes to `test2`. Hence, the rollback is necessary to correctly prevent the update after raising the error.

Comment: If a rollback is fired , i do not know if test 2 will be rolled back  because trigger is tied to the table1  so i am sopposing that it performs works only on the parent talble .

Comment: If rollback is done as part of the trigger, then all the uncommitted changes prior to that rollback will be lost. Any subsequent actions are not affected by past rollbacks. There is no link of rollback to any table, all uncommitted changes are treated in the same manner.